# Pass Arrays of Images to a Slider in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made a custom table view which have some labels and image view in which data comes from service and further it is passed to new view controller for details of the data. When the cell is clicked the data from the particular cell is passed to new vc and its detail is shown there. When the new vc opens a service is called which brings all the images behind that data which is to be shown in new vc. And i have used an Image slider to show all the images coming from service in that slider. I have used this slider [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svYNwvou8RM) , initially i used some static images than i passed the array of images to the sider , but i don't know why the images are not coming in the slider. My code is,

```
-(void)loadCustomerRecords
{

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];


    NSString *string1 = _propid.text;

    NSLog(@"ID is %@",string1);


    NSString *urll=@"My URL";

    NSString *string3 = [urll stringByAppendingString:string1];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:string3];

    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    NSString *parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"HI"];

    NSLog(@"parameter %@",parameters);
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                           NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                           if(error == nil)
                                                           {



                                                               NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

                                                               NSLog(@"MY Response %@ ", dictionary);

                                                               NSArray *results = [dictionary objectForKey:@"property_images"];
                                                               NSLog(@"RESULT %@ ", results);

                                                               for (NSDictionary * oneCustomer in results)
                                                               {
                                                                   // Create a new Customer record

                                                                   StringData * newCustomer = [[StringData alloc] init];


                                                                   newCustomer.images = [oneCustomer objectForKey:@"name"];

                                                                   NSLog(@"IMAGE: %@ ", newCustomer.images);


                                                                   [_Image1 addObject:newCustomer];


                                                                   NSString *imageURL = @"http://www.pk.house/frontend/propertyimages/";


                                                                   NSString *string3 = [imageURL stringByAppendingString:newCustomer.images];

                                                                   newCustomer.images = string3;

                                                                   NSLog(@"Image URL %@",string3);


                                                                  // [_Image1 addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"name"]];
                                                                   //NSLog(@"Array %@",_Image1);

                                                               }
                                                               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                   // This code will run once the JSON-loading section above has completed.


                                                               });




                                                               NSString *status=[dictionary valueForKey:@"property_images"];
                                                               NSLog(@"Status:%@",status);

                                                           }
                                                           else{
                                                               NSLog(@"network error:");


                                                           }
                                                       }];
    [dataTask resume];

}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be building an array of URLs.  I don't understand what that has to do with your question about passing data to view controllers.

Comment: Actually data is passed through segue and when any cell is clicked it pass data to new vc and at the same time a function is loaded which i have written above with the name loadCustomerRecords . Array is coming null, i don't know why but the response is coming correct from service in console. @PhillipMills

Comment: I think you are adding only image names into the array before appending it to base URL.

Comment: In console its come as abc.jpg (example).  But when i nslog array it comes null . @AnandKore

Comment: Are you trying to use the data before `loadCustomerRecords` completes?  Use `NSLog()` to see what order things happen in.

Comment: I have used nslog. Image url is coming right i have run that url in browser its showing the image , But its not showing image where i want. @PhillipMills

Answer (score 1):

Where did you initialised your _Image1 array?? and you are not adding updated string into array.

Try this :

```
-(void)loadCustomerRecords
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];


NSString *string1 = _propid.text;

NSLog(@"ID is %@",string1);


NSString *urll=@"My URL";

NSString *string3 = [urll stringByAppendingString:string1];

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:string3];

NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSMutableArray *_Image1 = [NSMutableArray new];

NSString *parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"HI"];

NSLog(@"parameter %@",parameters);
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
   NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
   if(error == nil)
   {
       NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

       NSLog(@"MY Response %@ ", dictionary);

       NSArray *results = [dictionary objectForKey:@"property_images"];
       NSLog(@"RESULT %@ ", results);

       for (NSDictionary * oneCustomer in results)
       {
           // Create a new Customer record

           StringData * newCustomer = [[StringData alloc] init];

           NSString *imageURL = @"http://www.pk.house/frontend/propertyimages/";
           NSString *string3 = [imageURL stringByAppendingString:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"name"]];
           newCustomer.images = string3;
           [_Image1 addObject:newCustomer];

           NSLog(@"Image URL %@",string3);


           // [_Image1 addObject:[oneCustomer objectForKey:@"name"]];
           //NSLog(@"Array %@",_Image1);

       }
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           // This code will run once the JSON-loading section above has completed.

           NSLog(@"Array of images :%@",_Image1);

       });




       NSString *status=[dictionary valueForKey:@"property_images"];
       NSLog(@"Status:%@",status);

   }
   else{
       NSLog(@"network error:");


   }


}];
    [dataTask resume];

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150441/discussion-on-answer-by-anand-kore-pass-arrays-of-images-to-a-slider-in-ios).